# How to collect chart data

Tags: mysql, database-design, charts

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but what is the process of collecting chart data? how it should be saved into DB?

For example, i have a tickets application, and i want to display a graphic chart to show how many tickets have been created in the last 30minutes, 1hour, 12hours, 24hours

How should i store this data in the database, to be able to use it in the interface later on?

My idea would be to create a `TicketsSummary` table, and for each ticket created, create a new record in the Db, with the `dateTime` created

Afterwards, in the ui, based on the filter (lets say last 30minutes), i pool from the database all the tickets where `CreatedDateTime >= (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.AddMinutes(-30))`

To make the interface up-to-date, i will pool every 60 seconds the data, and update the Chart.

Is this the correct approach?

```
Id            CreatedDateTime           Source
--------------------------------------------------
1             2017-04-13 05:17:29       Chat
2             2017-04-13 05:21:05       Email
3             2017-04-13 06:18:47       Chat
4             2017-04-13 06:49:10       Call Center
```

[image]

Comment: The approach seems sound to me.  Are you having trouble writing a specific query?

Comment: This approach is fine enough

Comment: On the server side you need to be storing the X axis to Y axis associations (with any additional metadata needed). Could take a look at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update to see how they do the dynamic updating.

Comment: @RaraituL what is chart source, chart is in html or any image loaded.

Comment: Thanks for answers! i will play with the data a bit before knowing exactly how to put all this together. @apokryfos please put answer as i will use the plugin to inspire :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a 2d chart is just an association of x values and their corresponding mapping to y values. In your case if you will basically be charting the result of a `SELECT DATE(CreatedDateTime) as X, COUNT(*) as Y FROM TicketsSummary GROUP BY X` (where X and Y are the values you need to display.

If you want this to update dynamically you can use Highcharts that support this out of the box (sort of).

Basically you would need something like the following example (slightly modified here). http://jsfiddle.net/w15e9chz/

The idea is you generate the graph data initially and when the chart is loaded (in events: load) you can set an interval for a function to trigger every 60 seconds to do another AJAX call to your serverside  and update the chart data.

Example:

```
events: {
       load: function () {

           // set up the updating of the chart each second
           setInterval(function () {
               var series = this.series[0]; //You can do this for each series if there are more
                   $.ajax({ url: "/data/url", success: function (newData) { 
                        series.setData(newData,true);//Assuming it is properly formatted.

                    });         
                }, 60000);
            }
        }
```